# What's the proper denomination for NA in pyspark dataframes?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I guess almost everything is in my question.
I just want to know how to call an NA value, how to write it.

Basically, I want to create a column full of NA in my dataframe. I could do it with NULL values (`None` in *pyspark*), see below:

`df=df.withColumn("Blabla", lit(None))`

But I don't find the equivalent for NA.

Has anyone an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float('nan')` for that. Working example below, hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1.0},
                            {'name': 'Bob', 'age': float('nan')}])
df = df.withColumn('more_nans',F.lit(float('nan')))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+---------+
|age| name|more_nans|
+---+-----+---------+
|1.0|Alice|      NaN|
|NaN|  Bob|      NaN|
+---+-----+---------+
```

Comment: But nan and NA are different, right? Plus, what if I am not dealing with float variables? Thanks for your answer

Comment: You are right. There is no ' Not Applicable' in Spark. There is `None`, and there is `NaN` for 'not a number'. Seeing as you knew how to create an entry for `None`, I just - incorrectly - assumed you were looking for the latter.

Comment: No problem. So I guess the best equivalent to the python/R `NA` is the `None` in (py)spark, would you also say so?

Comment: I personally would use `NaN` for numeric columns and a string `not applicable` for string columns, and use `None` when the data is actually missing so you are able to distinguish between those. But that is more a matter of preference.